# Xcode 11.2 is missing simulators

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode11

I've been using deployment target 12.2 and the iPhone SE simulator with Xcode 10.3 for a while.

Recently Xcode was updated to 11.2 and a new project I started with it uses 12.4 but all of the old simulators (iPhone SE, 5S,...) are missing in the "Run" dropdown list, only these are left:

[image]

The same ones are listed in the 12.2 project.

`Window - Devices and Simulators - Simulators` still lists all the simulators, old and new ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il8my.png)), and I can also add new ones (tried adding the SE one a second time - no success).

If I change the deployment target to 12.0, the iPhone SE is back but with every version newer than that it's the very limited list shown in the screenshot. For the Interface Builder I can still choose the iPhone SE though.

An actual iPhone SE can be updated to iOS 13, so why is it missing here and how do I get at least that simulator back for 12.2/12.4?

Comment: Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Components. You probably only have the iOS 12.0 simulator installed.

Comment: @rmaddy I have the iOS 12.0 and also the 13.2 (doesn't show up in the list though) simulator versions. It's been working fine with 12.0 for the last couple of months but it didn't after the update.

Comment: If you only have the iOS 12.0 and 13.2 simulators installed then if you set the Deployment Target to anything from 12.1 to 13.1 then why would you expect to see simulators for those versions? You can't have simulators appears for versions of the simulators you don't have installed.

Comment: @rmaddy It's been working with just 12.0 installed and a deployment target of 12.2 for months with the older Xcode version, so there had to be some kind of upwards-compatibility, which must have been removed in Xcode 11(.2?).

Comment: I just spent too much time not realizing that my `Deployment Info > Devices` was set to iPad instead of universal when all my iPhone sims were missing, so if you got here from google and that's you, there ya go.

Comment: Voted to reopen because the answer for the linked question didn't help to find a solution, as it's just an explanation on how to add a new simulator, which I already tried (as mentioned in my question). I want to post the way I fixed it as an answer (see my comment for Niki's answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can add any previous simulator like this

[image]

[image]

Click on plus button on bottom

[image]

[image]

> Here how it will be displayed in drop down with iOS 13.1

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the question and as seen on the screenshot I linked, all the old simulators are already listed in my Xcode's "Simulators" list (your second screenshot) but they don't show up in the dropdown list (your/my first screenshot). I already tried adding the SE a second time (also mentioned in the question) but that didn't work. Try it yourself.

Comment: I was able to do so and also able to run my app on simulator after testing only i've added this answer! :) FYI - i've attached the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: I just tested it again: Deleted the old SE entry, created a new one and even restarted Xcode but it's not in the list.

Comment: Okay, so what you can do is download 12.x iOS and then try to create simulator SE with that option so that we can conclude if there is a problem regards to iOS version or something else. And meanwhile try adding phone XR with iOS 13 version.

Comment: Why should I add the XR? Could you please add more text to your answer? It's always possible that images go down and then it would only consist of 3 sentences that don't help.

Comment: I found the problem: Previously it was fine to use a simulator version (eg. iOS 12.0) that was older than the deployment target (e.g. 12.4), as long as they were the same "base" version (so iOS 12). With Xcode 11 you need a simulator version that's the same/newer than the deployment target, so if that's 12.4, the simulator version has to be at least 12.4. I downloaded 12.4, which automatically added a 12.4 version for every simulator in `Window - Devices and Simulators - Simulators` (which 13.2 didn't). Now there are 3 for e.g. the iPhone 8 (12.0, 12.4, 13.2) and 2 for the rest (12.0, 12.4).