# How can I add XR simulator in my xcode 11.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using xcode 11.3.1 and it has some simulators alone. How can I add XR simulator in my xcode 11.3.1?

Comment: Why you need an `iPhone XR` simulator? Instead of `XR` you can use `iPhone 11` simulator.

Comment: But I am using simulator iPhone11 modal. But in real device of iPhone XR shows a different in UI

Comment: I have added the simulator iPhone XR by following this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728370/xcode-11-2-is-missing-simulators

Answer (score 2):

You can use the iPhone 11 simulator. Xcode only shows one model (simulator) for similar screen size so in you instance iPhone 11 has the same screen size as iPhone XR.

Comment: But I am using simulator iPhone11 modal. But in real device of XR shows a different in UI